# Why does my SwiftUI ActionSheet button/title display dark?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a common feature in my app where users can report posts but tapping a button and selecting "Report" from an action sheet.

For some reason my action-sheet **title**, .destructive AND .default **buttons** display darker than they should while the .cancel button displays as it should, see image below..

[image]

Below is my code and structure. I do not have any Extensions for ActionSheet that would be doing this **and it occurs globally in my app**, why could this be happening?

Thank you

**Parent List View for each post**

```
struct NewsFeed: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session : SessionStore
    @StateObject var newsfeedVM = NewsFeedViewModel() 

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(newsfeedVM.posts, id: \.id) { post in
                    PostCell(post: post)
                } 
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
        } 
    }
}
```

**PostCell subview with ActionSheet**

```
struct PostCell: View {
    @StateObject var postVM = PostViewModel()
    @State var post: Post
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PostHeadline(postVM: postVM, post: $post)
            PostMedia(postVM: postVM, post: $post)
            CommentCell(postVM: postVM, post: $post)
        }
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $postVM.showActionSheet) {
            ActionSheet(title: Text("Report a post"), buttons: [
                    .destructive(Text("Report")) {
                        self.reportPost(post: post)
                    },
                    .cancel() {
                        postVM.selectedPost = ""
                    }
            ])
        }
    }
    func reportPost(post: Post) {/// }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the darker background? Isn't that just transparency? Judging from Apple's design guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/action-sheets/) I'd say it looks exactly as it should  ...?

Comment: No that is fine but as you can see the actual button "Report" is darker than the "Cancel" button...??

Comment: Yes, and judging from the ui guidelines (and other apple apps) this seems how it's supposed to look. All buttons have transparency, except the cancel button ...

Comment: Its not a transparency though, its just darker... I think it looks bad